# Send MessageCard source JSON with HttpPOST Action

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I have a MessageCard which I am sending to my Teams channel via the Incoming Webhook connector. This is working well. However, the card has multiple sections and I would like to add an `Approve` button to each section which then refreshes the specific section once the `POST` completes.

I have read the [Message Card docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference) and more specifically the [Refresh Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#refresh-cards) section and it all makes sense. It leads me to think that the only way I would be able to achieve updating a specific section at a time would be to send the whole message card source JSON in the body of the `HttpPOST`, process the particular section in my custom API and send back the full message card JSON with the amended section. This seems fine to me but I cannot find a way to include the source message card JSON.

So I guess my questions are:

- Is there a specific variable that I can use in the body of my `HttpPOST` action to send the message card source?
- Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Here is my message card:

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "title": "A Title",
    "text": "Some text",
    "themeColor": "f1c40f",
    "sections": [
        {
            "startGroup": true,
            "activityTitle": "Title1",
            "potentialAction": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "body": "{{ variable containing source JSON for this whole card? }}",
                    "name": "Approve",
                    "target": "https://....."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "startGroup": true,
            "activityTitle": "Title2",
            "potentialAction": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "body": "{{ variable containing source JSON for this whole card? }}",
                    "name": "Approve",
                    "target": "https://....."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "startGroup": true,
            "activityTitle": "Title3",
            "potentialAction": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "body": "{{ variable containing source JSON for this whole card? }}",
                    "name": "Approve",
                    "target": "https://....."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to [update](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Controllers/TaskController.cs#L60) complete card body. Could you please give a try to [Sample connector for C#/.NET](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp) and let us know if you face any issue

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. However, how can I send the relevant information from my card body with the HttpPOST in order for my API to be able to rebuild the new card body to send back to Teams.

Comment: You can pass JSON object which could contain specific action details. Please take a look at [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Utils/TaskHelper.cs#L106) where we are passing title in JSON body. You could pass something like this: {'action': 'AddTextBox'}.